# How to find the amount of unique IDs (column A) where column B = 'Live' and column C is between a certain date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the amount of unique IDs from column A but where column B = 'Live' (contains 'live', 'New', 'In Progress', etc.) but also has to be within a certain date range in Column C (let's use 11/1/2022 to 11/15/2022).

I am not sure where to start, I have tried =SUM(IF(COUNTIF statements but can't get to the correct answer, I keep getting various errors. The date range is between cells C3:C1801 for reference but I want to see if there was a formula that would search for me as opposed to me having to scroll and see where the date range ended. Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Do you have Office 365?

Comment: What about `SUMIFS()` function?

Comment: Assuming you want the number of ID's then try countifs().